# Fetch JSON object in real-time and use that data to lookup a separate JSON API and display data in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I'm creating a React app that looks for a JSON post request at localhost:3005. That request will have a single JSON object with a single piece of data.

I then want to use that data to cross-reference a separate JSON REST API from localhost:. If a match is found I want to display all the data found on that REST API related to that aforementioned JSON object.

The app will actively look for a JSON POST request that looks like:

```
    {  
       "id":1,
       "phone_number":"8017971586"
    }
```

Then the app will look for that phone number like this:

`http://localhost:5789/fetch_data/{phone_number}`
`http://localhost:5789/fetch_data/8017971586`

If a JSON record is found then I want that data from the record to be displayed in the react app. If a JSON record is not found I want a way for a form to show up in react to add a record.

For example, going to http://localhost:5789/fetch_data/8017971586 will display this data:

```
   "Patients":[  
      {  
         "patientid":3,
         "guarantorid":3,
         "patientname":"Abbott, Ken",
         "birthdate":"1980-05-03",
         "age":"",
         "homephone":"8017971586",
         "otherphone":"",
         "mobilephone":"",
         "nextvisit":"",
         "lastvisit":"2015-03-07",
         "lastprophy":"2015-03-07",
         "balance":"",
         "insurance":"Lincoln National",
         "amountremaining":""
      },
      {  
         "patientid":4,
         "guarantorid":3,
         "patientname":"Abbott, Patricia",
         "birthdate":"1982-11-30",
         "age":"",
         "homephone":"8017971586",
         "otherphone":"8013751580",
         "mobilephone":"8017971212",
         "nextvisit":"",
         "lastvisit":"2015-03-07",
         "lastprophy":"2015-03-07",
         "balance":"",
         "insurance":"",
         "amountremaining":""
      },
      {  
         "patientid":4,
         "guarantorid":3,
         "patientname":"Abbott, Patricia",
         "birthdate":"1982-11-30",
         "age":"",
         "homephone":"8017971586",
         "otherphone":"8013751580",
         "mobilephone":"8017971212",
         "nextvisit":"",
         "lastvisit":"2015-03-07",
         "lastprophy":null,
         "balance":"",
         "insurance":"",
         "amountremaining":""
      },
      {  
         "patientid":5,
         "guarantorid":3,
         "patientname":"Abbott, Timothy",
         "birthdate":"2004-02-16",
         "age":"",
         "homephone":"8017971586",
         "otherphone":"",
         "mobilephone":"",
         "nextvisit":"",
         "lastvisit":"2015-03-07",
         "lastprophy":"2015-03-07",
         "balance":"",
         "insurance":"Lincoln National",
         "amountremaining":""
      }
   ]
}
```

I have Googled for days and unable to get exactly the results I'm looking for.

I'm using React & Node, however, would it be easier to use axios, express, socket.io, etc.?

Comment: Please can you share your current React code?